# Особенности запросов в c# sql

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть WinForm и на ней есть элемент report. В нем выводится процедура с параметрами, получаемыми из текстбокса. В процедуре указаны 2 параметра, и прописано, что если один не задан, то вывод все равно производится (isnull). Во время проверки в sql server это работает, а вот во время работы программы почему-то нет (то есть выводится отчет, только когда введены оба параметра).

Как можно это исправить?

Среда разработки Visual Stduio. БД - SQL Server. Язык - С#.

В программе:

```
string pcod = textBox1.Text;
string mcode = textBox2.Text;
this.NewSelectCommandTableAdapter.Fill(this.SelenaDataSet.NewSelectCommand, pcod, mcode);
```

В SQL запросе:

```
WHERE  (Table.s_fam = ISNULL(@pcod, Table.s_fam)) AND 
(Table.mcode_lpu = ISNULL(@mcode, Table.mcode_lpu))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WinForms для текстбокса нету понятия «не задан». Значение в текстбоксе всегда есть — если пользователь ничего не ввёл, то значением будет `""`.

Вам нужно проверять вручную, есть ли что-то в текстбоксе, и в случае необходимости передавать `NULL` так, как это правильно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сделал проверку и все заработало )

Comment: @Andy92: Пожалуйста!